# Collection.ToList<TResult>() extension method raises compile time error

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I cannot use `ToList<Tresult>()` extension method. The code I use is,

```
 return this.Semesters.ToList<ISemester>()
```

'Semesters' in above code is an EntityCollection. 
These using directives are already present,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

Still I cannot Compile as it keeps on complainting that 
`System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Semester>` does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>)` has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure Semester implements ISemester? As a test, I did this

```
interface ISemester { }
class Semester : ISemester { }

// ...

List<Semester> Semesters = new List<Semester>();
var query = Semesters.ToList<ISemester>();
```

Which is fine. However, change the class to simply be `class Semester { }`, and a syntactically-similar error to the one you reported surfaces.

Comment: Oops! Yeah, my fault! Semester was implementing a different interface. But the error was misleading though.

Answer (score 1):

Lack of a reference to the `System.Core` assembly? That would probably do it...

EDIT: There has to be *something* in the `System.Linq` namespace, or that would have failed to compile. I thought that maybe PFX was making that bit work... but assuming you're using .NET 4, the `ParallelEnumerable` class is *also* in `System.Core`.

What happens if you type `Enumerable.` - does that show anything?

Comment: Absent that reference, you would think `using System.Linq;` would highlight as invalid, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Anthony: I wondered whether ParallelEnumerable was in a different assembly, but it's not - at least not in .NET 4.

Comment: I have an existing reference to System.Core in my project references section.There is no such namespace, right?

Comment: @Threecoins: What do you mean by "there is no such namespace"? System.Core is an assembly, not a namespace - it's the assembly which contains System.Linq.Enumerable.

Comment: yes, i know, I already had reference to system.core assembly. I meant, since it was not a namespace I didn't mention it in the above question. Thanks for the support, problem was in my code as @Antony pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

are you missing

```
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Data.Entity
```

in your references?

Comment: If the compiler error mentions `EntityCollection<T>` then there's no using directive problems there...

Comment: Not in the using directives, I meant in the project references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your class `Semesters` does not inherit `IEnumerable<TSource>`.  I say this because in order to use `ToList<TSource>` `TSource` must be `Enumerable`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx